# Conversion of allyl alcohol to 2-chloro propanediol with HOCl

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, alcohols, hydrocarbons

going through the preparation of tri hydric alcohol(glycerol), i came across this reaction i.e. preparation of glycerol from propene. In the first step of this reaction, we did allyl substitution with chlorine followed by nucleophilic substitution with aq. KOH.
In the next step, we used HOCl to form 2-chloro propanediol. Why isn't it forming 3-chloro propanediol?

in other HOCl reactions on alkene, we can simply add HO(negative) and Cl(positive) on alkene in accordance with saytzeff.